# Sky for Linux (a Skype client) Crashes

Tags: crash, skype, installed-programs

I have a problem with [Sky for Linux](https://tel.red/linux_changelog.htm). This is an application that works with Skype for Business.

The issue is that the program closes on its own, crashing constantly. Not being an expert in these things, I can't understand what the problem is or how to solve it.

I have tried to contact the developers but nobody answers and, unfortunately, if you want have Skype for Business, this application is the only alternative that runs on Linux.

How can I solve this problem?

I use `Ubuntu 20.04.4 LTS` 
This are the crashes:

```
 drwxrwsrwt  2 root     whoopsie     4096 mar 16 09:20 .
 drwxr-xr-x 15 root     root         4096 giu 19  2020 ..
 -rw-r-----  1 moul     whoopsie 19438677 mar 16 09:20 
 _usr_lib_sky_sky.1000.crash
 -rw-rw-r--  1 moul     whoopsie        0 mar 16 09:20 
 _usr_lib_sky_sky.1000.upload
 -rw-------  1 whoopsie whoopsie       37 mar 16 09:20 
 _usr_lib_sky_sky.1000.uploaded
```

Comment: A little more information is going to be needed to help you identify the reason for the crash. Could you [edit] your question to include: (0) the version of Linux you're running (1) anything from your log files from around the time of the crash (you can find this information with the "Logs" application or via Terminal in `/var/log/syslog`). With this, it may be possible to identify the problem and offer a solution 

Comment: @ArturMeinild Apparently someone else originally thought that this question was about Sky Linux and didn't check back  to retract his close vote.

Comment: I added the linux version in the question

Comment: Going by the release dates and changelogs they've been very busy fixing bugs. Hopefully the next release will be better.

Comment: @ChanganAuto Do you have the same problem as me? So you say I just have to wait for a new release for them?

Comment: No, I was saying that whatever the problem is now it may or may not be fixed soon with the new release/version. I don't use "western" products/services.